# ¿Cómo muestro información en una imagen svg a modo de una card o globo de texto?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, bootstrap

Básicamente estoy creando un mapa con una imagen .svg para que el usuario pueda interactuar con cada uno de los territorios del mapa.

Mi consulta seria...
¿Cómo podría hacer que mediante un Hover al poner el cursor sobre X territorio este, muestre una card o una especie de globo de texto para colocar información general de cada área del mapa?

Answer (score 1):

Con bootstrap 5 puedes usar los tooltips por defecto. También puedes incluir alguna animación con CSS normal.

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

```css
.svg__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: stroke-width 300ms;
}
.svg__item:hover {
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/5.1.3/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.10.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<svg width="128.7mm" height="108.8mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 128.7 108.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="translate(-23.846 -44.745)">
  <rect x="24.346" y="45.245" width="127.7" height="107.8" fill="#800000" stroke="#000"/>
  <rect x="45.221" y="77.359" width="62.561" height="55.373" fill="#0f0" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1.1668" 
        class="svg__item" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip Arriba"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```